# Moya + Alamofire validate every request

Tags: swift, alamofire, moya

I'm using `Moya` + `Alamofire` and I'm trying to validate every request (like `Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get").validate()`) but within `Moya`.

But I can not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible now after you implement `validate` property on your `TargetType` implementation as described in [this example](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/docs/Examples/Advanced.md):

```
// MARK: - TargetType Protocol Implementation
extension MyService: TargetType {
    // ...

    // Validate setup is not required; defaults to `false`
    // for all requests unless specified otherwise.
    var validate: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .showUser, .showAccounts:
            return true
        case .createUser:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```